# Accessing API in Ruby when SOAP XML code is known

Tags: ruby, api, soap

I know there are a ton of posts on how to use Ruby to make SOAP requests (usually referencing the gem Savon) but I have not been able to make much sense of them (I am a complete noob to programming).  I am able to successfully access the API and perform my get requests using soaupUI and I am just looking for away to do these requests using Ruby.  Here are my inputs:

- soap = The XML code for the soap request
- POST "https://...."
- Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
- Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
- SOAPAction: "urn:provider/..."
- Content-Length: 1253
- Host: webservices....
- Connection: Keep-Alive
- User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)

where I have replaced identifying information with "...."  Is there a way I can simply use these inputs to initiate my soap requests?

Thank you!

EDITED: Ok, taking into account the following comments, here is a practice API I am trying to access.  The endpoint is http://www.thomas-bayer.com:80/axis2/services/BLZService, and I copied the soap from soupUI, where I was able to successfuly execute the request.

```
require 'net/http'
require 'net/https'

http = Net::HTTP.new('thomas-bayer.com', 80)
http.use_ssl = false
path = 'axis2/services/BLZService'

data = <<-EOF
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:blz="http://thomas-bayer.com/blz/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<blz:blz>70070010</blz:blz>
</blz:getBank>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
EOF

headers = {
'Referer' => 'http://www.appfusion.net',
'Content-Type' => 'text/xml',
'Host' => 'thomas-bayer.com'
}

resp, data = http.post(path, data, headers)
puts 'Code = ' + resp.code
puts 'Message = ' + resp.message
resp.each { |key, val| puts key + ' = ' + val }
puts data
```

When I run it returns a host of different errors.  Any help trouble shooting this would be much appreciated; here is the wsdl if that would be helpful:http://www.thomas-bayer.com/axis2/services/BLZService?wsdl if that

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Basically, how to use Ruby to perform get requests for an API, where I already have the xml code for the soap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a very easy way to do this using the soap.xml class in savon (version 1):

```
client = Savon.client("www.mywsdl.wsdl")
response = client.request :get_my_request do
soap.xml ='my xml code'
end
```